# Requisição angularjs sendo executada primeiro incorretamente

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, http

Em um controller, possuo duas requisições HTTP:

```
function findProfessionalEmail(professional) {
           EmailHunter.findProfessionalEmail(professional.company_name, professional.first_name,
                 professionalLastName).then(function (data) {
                    var score = data.data.data.score;

                    if (isProfessionalEmailScoreHigh(score)) {
                        vm.professional.email = data.data.data.email;
                    }
            });
        }
```

e

```
function checkAvailability(professional, callback) {
            findProfessionalEmail(professional);

            var cb = callback || angular.noop;
            CheckAvailability.save(getCheckAvailabilityDTO(vm.professional), function () {
                    console.log('Success!');
                    return cb();
            }, function (err) {
                console.log('Erro!');
                return cb(err);
            }).$promise;
        }
```

Ao invocar o segundo método "checkAvailability()", o sistema não executa minha requisição do método "findProfessionalEmail()" antes, e sempre executa a requisição do método "checkAvailability()" primeiro.

Porque esse comportamento?
Como consigo corrigi-lo?

Comment: O método findProfessionalEmail de EmailHunter espera a resposta de uma Promise (o que pode demorar um pouco), já o "save" de "CheckAvailability" passa um callback que é executado na hora. Aparentemente o jeito é colocar um chamada para a checkAvailability() na resposta da Promise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é que você está se perdendo no conceito de `async calls`.

Veja ambos `EmailHunter.findProfessionalEmail` e `CheckAvailability.save` fazem chamadas HTTP o que por padrão são chamadas assíncronas, por tanto você não garante ordem das chamadas como você fez, e pelo visto o `findProfessionalEmail` está fazendo mais processamento que o `CheckAvailability.save` por isso a resposta do `save` chega primeiro.

O que você precisa fazer é chamar o `CheckAvailability.save` dentro do `.then` da chamada do `EmailHunter.findProfessionalEmail` assim você faz uso do conceito de [promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) do **angular**.

O melhor a ser feito seria

```
function checkAvailability(professional, callback) {

            var cb = callback || angular.noop;
            CheckAvailability.save(getCheckAvailabilityDTO(vm.professional), function () {
                    console.log('Success!');
                    return cb();
            }, function (err) {
                console.log('Erro!');
                return cb(err);
            }).$promise;
        }

function findProfessionalEmail(professional, checkAvailabilityCallBack) {
           EmailHunter.findProfessionalEmail(professional.company_name, professional.first_name,
                 professionalLastName).then(function (data) {
                    var score = data.data.data.score;

                    if (isProfessionalEmailScoreHigh(score)) {
                        vm.professional.email = data.data.data.email;
                    }

                    checkAvailabilityCallBack(vm.professional)
            });
        }
```

E chamar assim:

```
findProfessionalEmail(professional, checkAvailability);
```